# PHP - DELETE function not working

Tags: php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$select_categories = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories)) {
$cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
$cat_title = $row['cat_title'];

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>{$cat_id}</td>";
echo "<td>{$cat_title}</td>";
echo "<td><a href='categories.php?delete={$cat_id}'>Delete</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";

}

?>

<?php 

//DELETE QUERY;

if(isset($_GET['detele'])) {

$the_cat_id = $_GET['delete'];
$query = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE cat_id = {$the_cat_id} ";
$delete_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
header("Location: categories.php");
}

?>
```

So, I have this page that is showing me every single item (category) from my database, and I have them sorted by id and everything works just fine except only one thing. When I try to delete an item, nothing happens. The thing is I have no errors and that is making me wander why is not working.

Comment: Note: Your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection attacks**.  You're basically allowing users to execute any code they want on your database.

Comment: I know. Right now I'm learning php and nothing more and before security I want to learn the basics.

Comment: Security *is* "the basics".  Why would you intentionally learn to do things *poorly*?  "I'll fix it later" is the most damaging and pervasive delusion in all of software development.

Comment: Dude, relax. I'm watching a tutorial about this. If you can recommand something better for a beginner, please do. I've seen something about security and that area will be covered later on. I do not know why, but this is the way it was created. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

might be spelling mistake in   `if(isset($_GET['detele']))`, `detele` should be `delete` check your code

Comment: yeah, that was the mistake. Now I get an error in the header() line.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\includes\admin_navigation.php:88) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\categories.php on line ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Yes spelling mistake so it will never go into condition and never run delete query.
Please correct it and confirm.

Incorrect :

```
if(isset($_GET['detele']))
```

Correct:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']))
```

Comment: I corrected it and it works. :)